# Scala: Mixing traits with the "same" abstract type member

Tags: scala, types, compiler-errors

I have been looking at the [paper](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/namin/unsound/master/doc/unsound-oopsla16.pdf) on the type system of Java and Scala being unsound. To better understand the problem, I have been trying to play around with a smaller related problem.

I have the following types:

```
class Parent
class Child extends Parent
class Grandchild extends Child
class GrandGrandchild extends Grandchild
```

Here are some traits with constrained abstract types:

```
trait LowerBound[T] extends{
  type M >: T
}

trait UpperBound[U] extends{
  type M <: U
}
```

I understand that the problem arising here is that the types `T` and `U` in `UpperBound` and `LowerBound` are not related. So mixing them can be problematic.

I can see that I can create an object/val by providing the abstract type:

```
object FamilyMember extends LowerBound[GrandGrandchild] with UpperBound[Parent] {
  type M = Child
}
```

but I fail in defining a trait like the following:

```
trait FamilyTreeConstraint extends LowerBound[GrandGrandchild] with UpperBound[Parent]
```

I get:

> overriding type M in trait LowerBound with bounds >: A$A131.this.GrandGrandchild;
>    type M in trait UpperBound with bounds <: A$A131.this.Parent has incompatible type

Now if I didn't have any concrete types, the parameterised `FamilyConstraint` would be equivalent to:

```
trait UpperLower[T,U]{
   type M >: T <: U
}
```

on which I understand the error. as T and U are unrelated.

But the Family Constraint type above is not abstract and actually has concrete types. Ie I would have imagined the compiler to end up with this:

```
trait UpperLowerConcrete{
   type M >: GrandGrandchild <: Parent
}
```

Where I would be allowed to refine M as `Child` or `GrandChild` .However it doesn't turn into above and gives the same error as the abstract case.

- Why?
- Also, am I right in thinking that type-refinements are applied first and then type-constraints are checked?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reasons for this behavior but from my experience it is often necessary to explicitly override `type`  definition inside a sub-class/trait if its constraints are changed. What I mean is that once you specify restrictions for `M` explicitly in your `FamilyTreeConstraint`, the compiler is satisfied

```
trait FamilyTreeConstraint extends LowerBound[GrandGrandchild] with UpperBound[Parent] {
  override type M >: Grandchild <: Parent
}
```

See it [online](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bIdGM3n9SJi5YXNH8DgbhQ)